# Spelling mistake on Careers Profile Completeness Score under Education

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, spelling

Appears if one or more education entries don't have achievements documented and you click the **more...** link.

Just one letter.

> archievements

should be changed to

> achievements

[image: StackOverflow Careers Completeness Score Spelling Mistake]

Comment: Or it could be a portmanteau of Archived achievements.

Answer (score 4):

This has been fixed. We'll try to stop making up words.

Comment: Sweet!  Although you'll never know what'll catch on unless you try ;)